# MongoDB how to delete document by count fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image]

My collection has data with 10000+ records in the fields. It has two documents with 111 fields and 7 fields respectively.

I want to delete the document in collection with 7 fields. Please help suggest a query for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a document with 7 fields, use the [`db.collection.deleteOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#mongodb-method-db.collection.deleteOne) method with the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) query operator which allows you to use aggregate operators like [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objecttoarray/) and [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to get the number of fields in the document using the system variable [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) as reference to the root document.

The following operation will delete a single document with `n` number of fields:

```
var n = 7;
db.collection.deleteOne({
    $expr: {
        $eq: [
            { $size: { $objectToArray: '$$ROOT' } },
            n // n = 7
        ]
    }    
});
```